# Why result of compose webview and xml webview is not the same?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, android-compose

xml webView can render the result from url which is image of test qr code.
but when I use compose webView it is not working.

url is

```
https://dev-api.apps.kpc-dev.com/contents/download?url=https://api.omise.co/charges/chrg_test_5yqu1qyc4qjs33sb1am/documents/docu_test_5yqu1r37cb8u21865mg/downloads/B8822733EE0EF444
```

xml webivew version

```
findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView).apply {
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        loadUrl(url)
    }
```

compose webview version

```
AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(170.dp)
                        .height(200.dp),
                    factory = { context ->
                        WebView(context).apply {
                            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
                            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                            webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                            }
                            loadUrl(url)
                        }
                    },
                    update = { webView ->
                    }
                )
```